# Image is taking much time to load using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have following Jquery code to change image SRC of the page. Image srcs are dynamic on page. Once they load, I m using jquery code to change src. If changed SRC image is not found, I am loading original one.

Below is code..

```
function changeThePath(imagePath){
    var imageNamePath = imagePath;
    var imageLocalPath ='';

    var s = imageNamePath.split("/");
    for( i = 0; i < s.length-1;i++ ){
            imageLocalPath = imageLocalPath+s[i]+'/';
    }
    console.log("imageLocalPath "+imageLocalPath);
    s=s[s.length-1];
    s=s.split(".")[0]+"_newImage."+s.split(".")[1];
    console.log("final modified: "+(imageLocalPath+s));
    return imageLocalPath+s;

}

var originalPath  = jQuery("li.toycar img").attr('src');
console.log("ORIGINAL PAT.. "+originalPath);
var newPath=changeToFeaturedCar(originalPath);
jQuery("li.toycar img").attr('src',newPath);

jQuery("li.toycar img").error(function () {
    console.log("error loading image"); 
    jQuery(this).attr("src", originalPath);
});
```

Code is fine. Image is changing. But it's taking much time. How can I reduce it ??

Please help.

Comment: what do you mean with "it's taking too much time". Is the actual request slower?

Comment: when page get load.. By default.. Section is none.. When Jquery completes.. I am making that section to BLOCK. But then It shows original Image then browser shows loading for sometime and then my image changes to modified one ( changeThePath() function one ).

Answer (score 0):

Use following logic, setting source to none appended element:

```
var $imgs = jQuery("li.toycar img"),
    newPath = changeToFeaturedCar(originalPath);
$('<img/>', {
    src: newPath,
    load: function () {
        $imgs.attr('src', newPath); // would used cached version now!
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("error loading 'newPath' image");
    }
});
```

Comment: I have so many images on page. Will it execute for all <img> section ?

Comment: @user3095179 You have to handle it. Your posted code handle it only for one newPath.

Comment: This logic.. I just applies.. It is changing required code.. BUT taking same amount of time.. STILL..

Comment: jQuery('<img/>', {
           src: newPath,
           load: function () {
            console.log("I AM IN LOAD..");  
            $imgs.attr('src', newPath);
           },
           error: function () {
            console.log("error loading 'newPath' image");
            $imgs.attr('src', originalPath);
           }
          });    console i did put.. printing in the end. when page load completes

Comment: @user3095179 On error, and because you didn't previously changed image path, you don't need to reset it to `originalPath`, it is still the `originalPath` as image source

Comment: If u check this.. I am  printing "I AM IN LOAD".. It's printing at the end

Comment: Can i make this piece of code synchronous. So after executing this code only, it goes to next line.. IS there any way ??

Comment: @user3095179 Events are working in `async` way. You last comment doesn't make much sense to me >> `So after executing this code only, it goes to next line` <<, i'm sorry. You'd have better to provide a concrete sample in question itself regarding your issue